Inconsistency of copying and pasting curly quotation marks in the notebook
When my string( Input or Output Cell style) or text( Text Cell style) contains curly quotation marks “ ( U+201C ) or ” ( U+201D ), when I copy this single symbol from the notebook to another place, it will become " ( U+0022 ). When I copy the whole text from the notebook to another place, the part corresponding to the curly quotes becomes \[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote] or \[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote], for example:
Text(Copied from a book) in Notebook:


Select either form of the whole text, and copy and paste here:

"请听着，那种没读过几篇\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]玻尔\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]\
就乱发梦呓，胡扯什么\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]玻尔与易经\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]\
的作法，实在是一种无理、无礼、无知、无聊、无耻的江湖胡闹，是北京俗语所说的一种\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]霸王硬上弓\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]。"


Use the function CopyToClipboard :

请听着，那种没读过几篇"玻尔"就乱发梦呓，胡扯什么"玻尔与易经"的作法，实在是一种无理、无礼、无知、无聊、无耻的江湖胡闹，是北京俗语所说的一种"霸王硬上弓"。


Only select the curly quote “ and copy and paste it here:

"

None of these three are what I want, I want to get the original form:
请听着，那种没读过几篇“玻尔”就乱发梦呓，胡扯什么“玻尔与易经”的作法，实在是一种无理、无礼、无知、无聊、无耻的江湖胡闹，是北京俗语所说的一种“霸王硬上弓”。

So how can I get the original form from Mathematica, and what causes copy-paste inconsistency? Of course, it may be biased to say that this is inconsistent, because it may treat curly quotation marks “ or ” as quotation marks " at the beginning when copying.
The curly quotation marks are encoded normally in the notebook, for example:

In[1]:= BaseForm[#, 16] & /@ ToCharacterCode["“”\""]

Similar problems exist with other punctuation marks, such as the long dash —( U+2014 ).

I suspect the problem you report arises from Mathematica's interactions with the system clipboard. There are a number of Qs and As on that subject on the site, might be worth while you having a look at them. Not sure you'll find a simple answer though.
